# Limitar quantidade de caracteres modo bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, layout-responsivo

preciso adicionar uma limitação de caracteres. 
Quero que a página principal exiba somente uma porcentagem de caracteres, exemplo 100 e quando o usuário acessar aquela postagem, mostrar a noticia completa.

Mas minha dúvida é que estou trabalhando com bootstrap, como eu faria isso ?

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma infinidade de formas de fazer isso, algumas apenas com CSS e outras envolvendo JavaScript.

Vou te dar uma solução com CSS. Nessa técnica imagine que os "..." sempre estão lá, mas tem um elemento por cima deles que quando é atingido pelo texto ele pula para a linha de baixo e deixa os "..." visíveis. Tudo isso é possível usando `::before` e `::after` e `overflow:hidden` no `container` O legal dessa técnica é que se o texto for menor que 100 characteres os "..." não aparecem!

*Nesse exemplo o texto está com os valores default do browser, só ajustei a largura da div para caberem exatamente 100 caracteres.*

Veja o exemplo:

```css
div {
    width: 230px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    text-align: justify;
}
.block-with-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative; 
  line-height: 1.2em;
  max-height: 3.6em; 
  text-align: justify;  
  margin-right: -1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}.block-with-text:before {
  content: '...';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}.block-with-text:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<p>MAIS de 100 characters</p>
<div class="block-with-text ">
    Lorem, ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Wsit amet, até aqui tem 100! Resto do rexto que não aparece!
</div>
<br>
<p>MENOS de 100 characters</p>
<div class="block-with-text ">
    Lorem, ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Menos de 100
</div>
<br>
<p>Mais de 100 characters e <strong>sem overflow no container</strong> para vc ver</p>
<div class="block-with-text " style="overflow: visible">
    Lorem, ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Wsit amet, até aqui tem 100! Resto do texto que não aparece pelo overflow!
</div>
```

[Fonte de referência](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/)

---

**OBS1:** Não indico a propriedade css `line-clamp` pois o suporte dos browsers ainda é muito pequeno, nem no FireFox funciona como vc pode consultar aqui: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp

**OBS2:** nesse artigo existe uma infinidade de formas que podem te atender umas corssbrowser outras nem tanto e algumas com JS https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!

Comment: @DemetriusReis legal que deu certo, essa é a melhor forma que eu conheço usando CSS.