# Definir largura de div que contém paragráfo

Tags: css

Tenho um parágrafo com um texto dentro `.descBlog`. Defini a largura desse parágrafo `width: 300ch`, porém, quero que tenha uma `div` superior com `width: 300px`. Eu gostaria que com a limitação de 300 caracteres, e com uma div superior de 300px, ele quebrasse e jogasse o conteúdo do parágrafo para baixo.

```css
p.descBlog {
  max-width: 300ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="superior">    
<p class="descBlog">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at vehicula turpis. Donec condimentum sagittis mi sed sollicitudin. In id justo molestie, cursus libero non, auctor ante. Praesent efficitur ac purus ac pellentesque. Pellentesque varius
  nisi quis urna placerat fermentum. Quisque imperdiet est nec nibh tempus viverra. Morbi massa metus, porta eu ex ac, dignissim ultricies felis.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Como assim "_div superior_"?

Comment: @dvd editei a pergunta.

Comment: Pode vir tags HTML no meio do texto?

Comment: @dvd Não, apenas texto.

Comment: Acho que isso pode te interessar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293488/limitar-quantidade-de-caracteres-modo-bootstrap/293504#293504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só com CSS é impossível, porque o `text-overflow: ellipsis;` requer `overflow: hidden;` e `white-space: nowrap;`, o que é um problema porque não vai funcionar em mais de uma linha de texto, só vai funcionar em uma linha, e o resto texto será ignorado.

Para tais situações você pode usar o JavaScript usando o método `.substring()`, onde você pode pegar apenas o número de caracteres desejado e concatenando com "..." onde o resultado é este (explicações no código):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ // quando o DOM estiver carregado
   var descs = document.querySelectorAll(".descBlog"); // selecione todas as classes
   var text_limit = 300; // limite de caracteres, sem contar "..."
   for(var x=0; x<descs.length; x++){ // percorre todos os elementos da classe
      var desc_txt = descs[x].textContent; // pega o texto
      descs[x].textContent = desc_txt.substring(0, 300)+"..."; // troca o texto por apenas os 300 primeiros caracteres
      descs[x].style.display = "inline"; // exibe o elemento
   }
});
```

```css
p.descBlog {
   display: none; /* comece com oculto para não aparecer com todo o texto antes do DOM estiver pronto*/
}

.superior{
   width: 300px;
   background: red; /* fundo só para exemplo, pode apagar isso*/
}
```

```html
<div class="superior">    
   <p class="descBlog">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at vehicula turpis. Donec condimentum sagittis mi sed sollicitudin. In id justo molestie, cursus libero non, auctor ante. Praesent efficitur ac purus ac pellentesque. Pellentesque varius nisi quis urna placerat fermentum. Quisque impe est nec nibh tempus viverra. Morbi massa metus, porta eu ex ac, dignissim ultricies felis.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Com CSS na div** determine aa largura `width: 300px;` na classe da div

```
.superior{
  width: 300px;
}
```

> Segue exemplo abaixo

```css
p.descBlog {
  max-width: 300ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.superior{
   width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="superior"> 
<p class="descBlog">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at vehicula turpis. Donec condimentum sagittis mi sed sollicitudin. In id justo molestie, cursus libero non, auctor ante. Praesent efficitur ac purus ac pellentesque. Pellentesque varius
  nisi quis urna placerat fermentum. Quisque imperdiet est nec nibh tempus viverra. Morbi massa metus, porta eu ex ac, dignissim ultricies felis.</p>
</div>
```

**Com javascript puro**

```js
      var texto = document.getElementById("descBlog").innerText;
      texto = texto.substr(0, 300)+"...";
      document.getElementById("descBlog").innerText=texto
```

```css
    #superior {
      width: 300px; 
    }
```

```html
    <div id="superior">
      <p id="descBlog">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nisi ligula, dapibus a volutpat sit amet, mattis et dui. Nunc porttitor accumsan orci id luctus. Phasellus ipsum metus, tincidunt non rhoncus id, dictum a lectus. Nam sed ipsum a urna ac
        quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam at vehicula turpis. Donec condimentum sagittis mi sed sollicitudin. In id justo molestie, cursus libero non, auctor ante. Praesent efficitur ac purus ac pellentesque. Pellentesque varius
      nisi quis urna placerat fermentum. Quisque imperdiet est nec nibh tempus viverra. Morbi massa metus, porta eu ex ac, dignissim ultricies felis.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Se eu fizer assim, o .descBlog vai ter 300px, e no caso, o max-width: 300ch não surtira efeito.
Eu gostaria que com a limitação de 300 caracteres, e com uma div superior de 300px, ele quebrasse e jogasse o conteúdo do parágrafo para baixo.

Comment: @FelipeGoulart, então coloca isso na pergunta!

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: @FelipeGoulart, acho que vai ter que recorrer a JavaScript